# Textures being intensified when importing to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: EG.]

when i import image to unity it breaks eg.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you import as sRGB, while your textures are plain RGB?

Comment: How do i do that exactly?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LinearRendering-LinearTextures.html

Comment: Didnt work Sry!

Comment: Does setting Compression to None make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out I just set alpha is transparency to true